# split a nested dictionary in jinja2 template flask in bootstrap over n number of columns

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

My apologies if this seems simple I've been at it for hours and cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Requirement:

I'm trying to populate a table with dates from a sql table and create a dynamic PDF

in pictures I'm trying to obtain this :

[image]

but my best attempt only gets me here :

[image]

(see repeated value 12 Sept which should go into col2)

I've chosen to populate my sql table into a dictionary which rougly looks like this

```
cal_dict = {'12 Sept 2020' : 'Event_1', '15 Sept 2020' : None, '22 Sept 2020' : 'Closed'}
```

now in my Jinja2 template, whenever the word 'Closed' appears I need to use the `<del></del>` tags to strike out some text.

now if i populate my jinja2 flask template with my dictionary it comes out like so

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <tbody>
        {% for k,v in cal_dict.items() %}
            {% if v == 'Closed' %}
            <tr>
                <td><del>{{ k }} </del></td>
            {% elif v == None %}
                <td><del>{{ k }} </del></td>
            {% else %}
                <td> {{ k + '- ' + v }}
            {% endif %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
            
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

For all intens and purposes this works very well, however I have my issue is that my dictionary is quite large so I want to split this dictionary equally over 4 columns, so I create a further nested dictionary like so

```
cal_dict_nest = {0 :{'12 Sept 2020' : 'Event 1', '15 Sept 2020' : None, '22 Sept 2020' : 'Closed'}, 
1 : {'22 Oct 2020' : 'Event 2', '31 Dec 2020' : 'Closed', '05 Jan 2021' : 'Event 3'} }
```

I then call each outer key manually (0,1,2,3) in my case like so :

I realise four for loops is a very bad way to do things but I couldn't think of a different way to do this, a single loop of the outer keys and then inner keys nets me a single column not 4.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <tbody>
        {% for k,v in cal_dict[0].items() %}
            {% if v == 'Closed' %}
            <tr>
                <td><del>{{ k }} </del></td>
            {% elif v == None %}
                <td><del>{{ k }} </del></td>
            {% else %}
                <td> {{ k + '- ' + v }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% for k,v in cal_dict[1].items() %}
            {% if v == 'Closed' %}
            <tr>
                <td><del>{{ k }} </del></td>
            {% elif v == None %}
                <td><del>{{ k }} </del></td>
            {% else %}
                <td> {{ k + '- ' + v }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Jinja has a special internally built filter for batching an iterable. You don't have to use nested dicts to achieve a 4-column table. You can use the [batch](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#batch) filter to grab every 4 items from your dictionary to then generate each row of the table. There is an excellent example of the filter being used in a table context in the link provided.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr you are my hero, seriously I spent all day trying to re-create the logic of this function. can you post this as an answer if possible?

Comment: Glad I could help! And done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`batch`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#batch) filter provided by jinja. It's an internally built filter that generates batches of lists from an iterable and is perfect for your use case.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <tbody>
        {% for row in cal_dict.items()|batch(4) %}
            <tr>
            {% for k, v in row %}
                {% if v == 'Closed' or v is None %}
                    <td><del>{{ k }}</del></td>
                {% else %}
                    <td>{{ k + '- ' + v }}</td>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```